# Swift 4 sort dictionary by the first value

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sorting, dictionary

I'm working on an iOS app using Swift 4 and I have a dictionary like this:

```
var list = [
"US" : ["United-States","$"], 
"FR" : ["France","€"],
"CN" :["China", "¥"]
]
```

I would like to sort a `UITableView` based on this dictionary by the first value of each key in order to get the following result:

```
China
France
United-States
```

This this possible?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. You better define a structure around your data model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `map` to create an array of tuples with your country's `symbol`, `name`, and `currency`, and then sort that array by `name`:

```
let list = ["US" : ["United-States","$"],
            "FR" : ["France","€"],
            "CN" : ["China", "¥"]]

let newlist = list.map { (symbol: $0.key, name: $0.value.first ?? "", currency: $0.value.dropFirst().first ?? "")}.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }

print(newlist)
```

> [(symbol: "CN", name: "China", currency: "¥"), (symbol: "FR", name: "France", currency: "€"), (symbol: "US", name: "United-States", currency: "$")]

This will allow you to access all of the information easily for your table:

```
let symbol = newlist[indexPath.row].symbol
let name = newlist[indexPath.row].name
let currency = newlist[indexPath.row].currency
```

or just:

```
let (symbol, name, currency) = newlist[indexPath.row]
```

---

For your more complicated dictionary...

One of your problems is that your `value` is now `[Any]`, so conditional casts are needed.  Also, break up creation of the `newlist` and the sorting.

```
let list = ["US" : ["United-States","$","My comment", 10],
            "FR" : ["France","€", "My super comment", 20],
            "CA" : ["Canada","$", "Whatever", 15],
            "CN" : ["China", "¥", "Final comment", 5]]

let newlist = list.map { (symbol: $0.key,
                          name: $0.value.first as? String ?? "",
                          currency: $0.value.dropFirst().first as? String ?? "",
                          comment: $0.value.dropFirst(2).first as? String ?? "",
                          value: $0.value.dropFirst(3).first as? Int ?? 0) }

let sortedlist = newlist.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }
print(sortedlist)
```

> [(symbol: "CA", name: "Canada", currency: "$", comment: "Whatever", value: 15), (symbol: "CN", name: "China", currency: "¥", comment: "Final comment", value: 5), (symbol: "FR", name: "France", currency: "€", comment: "My super comment", value: 20), (symbol: "US", name: "United-States", currency: "$", comment: "My comment", value: 10)]

Comment: just answered you with few comments

Comment: TANKS ! I got it now

Answer (score 2):

You can get your dictionary values (arrays), map their first element and sort it:

```
let list = ["US" : ["United-States","$"],
            "FR" : ["France","€"],
            "CN" : ["China", "¥"]]

let countries = list.values.compactMap{$0.first}.sorted()

print(countries)    // ["China", "France", "United-States"]
```

---

Another options is to create a struct for your currency, create a custom initializer that takes a key value pair and make it conform to Comparable protocol:

```
struct Currency: CustomStringConvertible, Comparable {
    let name: String
    let code: String
    let symbol: String
    init?(currency: (key: String, value: [String])) {
        guard currency.value.count == 2 else { return nil }
        self.code = currency.key
        self.name = currency.value.first!
        self.symbol = currency.value.last!
    }

    var description: String {
        return "Code: \(code)\nName: \(name)\nSynmbol: \(symbol)\n"
    }
}
extension Currency {
    static func <(lhs: Currency, rhs: Currency) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name < rhs.name
    }
}
```

---

```
let list = ["US" : ["United-States","$"],
            "FR" : ["France","€"],
            "CN" :["China", "¥"]]

let currencies = list.compactMap(Currency.init).sorted()
currencies.map({print($0)})
```

This will print:

> Code: CN
>
> Name: China
>
> Synmbol: ¥
>
> Code: FR
>
> Name: France
>
> Synmbol: €
>
> Code: US
>
> Name: United-States
>
> Synmbol: $

Comment: You might want to sort the keys by the first value so that OP can easily access country abbreviation and currency symbol, or combine those elements into the array somehow.

Comment: I know we can do that but seems like he is just interest in the countries list. I would make a custom structure if OP needs those values also.

Comment: Thank you ! but i've got a problem in xcode : Missing argument for parameter 'by' in call. Moreover, I'm not just interested in the countries list, my goal is to reorganise my Dictionary before printing the datas in a UITableView. Because for now, the list is randomly printed in the app..

Comment: Thanks Leo, i'm gonna try it as well !