# Retrieve first dictionary value swift

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary

I have this type of dictionary:

```
var dict = [1: ["Value-1-1", "", ""],
            2: ["", "Value-2-2", "Value-2-3"], 
            3: ["Value-3-1", "Value-3-2", ""],
            4: ["Value-4-1", "", "Value-4-3"],
            5: ["", "", "Value-5-3"]]
```

I need to loop over this dictionary and get only first value that is not nil under every key and append it into array.

So, in the end, my array would look like:

```
var array = ["Value-1-1", "Value-2-2", "Value3-1", "Value-4-1", "Value-5-3"]
```

I have read this question here - [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51886161/swift-4-sort-dictionary-by-the-first-value) but it doesn't cover empty values and I'm wondering if it's possible to do, without map, but using for in or while loops?

Would be grateful if anyone could provide code example of such loop. Thanks!

Comment: *"... first value that is not nil ..."* – `""` is an empty string not “nil.” And why don't you want to use map()?

Comment: That's why I'm here, on SO. I'm wondering if you can avoid using map in this case... if not - then how should you avoid empty strings and loop over it with map?

Comment: What does this data structure represent? It's completely bizarre, and looks like it would be very difficult to work with.

Comment: @ Alexander key - is product id, value - product images organized in such order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:
It's a good initiative when learning programming to use manual for loop instead of magical methods like `map()`, etc, in an algorithmic way. They do loop, but they are implicit.
Here, I used the `sorted()` (because else it can be a little long).
I also used `first(where:)`, it finds the first non-empty value. It also can be replaced with a while loop, but I didn't know if you wanted a for loop to.

```
var dict = [1: ["Value-1-1", "", ""],
            2: ["", "Value-2-2", "Value-2-3"],
            3: ["Value-3-1", "Value-3-2", ""],
            4: ["Value-4-1", "", "Value-4-3"],
            5: ["", "", "Value-5-3"]]
var finalArray = [String]()
let keys = Array(dict.keys).sorted(by: { return $0<$1 }) // because keys aren't sorted
for aKey in keys {
    if let anArrayValue = dict[aKey], let firstNonEmptyValue = anArrayValue.first(where: { !$0.isEmpty }) {
        finalArray.append(firstNonEmptyValue)
    }
}
print("finalArray: \(finalArray)")
```

See [@Martin R answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52278750/1801544) for the version with "higher level" methods, but more complicated to understand for debutants (chaining, closures, etc.). It does the same, just more compact, less explicit.

Comment: Or: `if let anArrayValue = dict[aKey], let firstNonEmptyValue = anArrayValue.first(where:...)` to get rid of the optional chaining.

Comment: Good point. I think XCode added itself the "?", didn't noticed it.

Comment: @Larme, thanks for your answer. Marked as accepted one, since it's more easier for me as beginner to understand.

Comment: Or more simply: `let keys = dict.keys.sorted()`

Comment: @Larme - I have additional question: if you have empty values - it skips, but what should I do, if I want to store empty values? For instance, if `[6: ["","",""]]` - it skips, but I want to store it anyway. Thanks in advance!

Comment: After the if let: else { finalArray.append(””)}

Comment: @Larme thanks, that helped! You saved my day! I think, I should read guides about sorting yet another time :)

Answer (score 4):

Sort the dictionary by the keys to get a well-defined order,
this gives an array of key/value pairs.
Then use `compactMap()` and `first(where:)` to map each pair to
the first non-empty string in the value array (if it exists):

```
let dict = [1: ["Value-1-1", "", ""],
            2: ["", "Value-2-2", "Value-2-3"],
            3: ["Value-3-1", "Value-3-2", ""],
            4: ["Value-4-1", "", "Value-4-3"],
            5: ["", "", "Value-5-3"]]


let array = dict.sorted(by: { $0.key < $1.key })
    .compactMap { $0.value.first(where: { !$0.isEmpty }) }

print(array) // ["Value-1-1", "Value-2-2", "Value-3-1", "Value-4-1", "Value-5-3"]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I'll mark @Larme answer as accepted one, since it's more easier to understand. Thanks again for help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve it but it does use flatMap:

```
var dict = [1: ["Value-1-1", "", ""],
            2: ["", "Value-2-2", "Value-2-3"],
            3: ["Value-3-1", "Value-3-2", ""],
            4: ["Value-4-1", "", "Value-4-3"],
            5: ["", "", "Value-5-3"]]

let newArray = dict.keys.flatMap({
    dict[$0]?.first(where: { !$0.isEmpty })
}).sorted()

print(newArray)
```

Output:

> ["Value-1-1", "Value-2-2", "Value-3-1", "Value-4-1", "Value-5-3"]

Comment: I know it's not that clear in author's question, but you sorted the values, and not the keys. So if instead of "Value-Key-Index", it was "Value-Index-Value", your result would be different.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a nice and clear pipeline that achieves what you want:

```
let dict = [1: ["Value-1-1", "", ""],
            2: ["", "Value-2-2", "Value-2-3"],
            3: ["Value-3-1", "Value-3-2", ""],
            4: ["Value-4-1", "", "Value-4-3"],
            5: ["", "", "Value-5-3"]]

let result = dict.values // we only care about values
    .compactMap { value in value.first(where: { !$0.isEmpty }) } // extract the first non-empty string, filter out nils (i.e. empty arrays or arrays made up only of empty strings
    .sorted() // sort the results
print(result) // ["Value-1-1", "Value-2-2", "Value-3-1", "Value-4-1", "Value-5-3"]
```

Each step of the pipeline, even if written in a concise form, transmits the intent, making it easier to resonate about what it does.

We could've get a little bit more concise with step 2: `compactMap { $0.first { !$0.isEmpty } }`, IMO this would've been as concise as the above code, however it might be just my feeling.